# Unable to access the fields of selecteditem on listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a listview on mouse double click i am trying to get the name and path of the item selected, I have written following code but i am getting "System.NullReferenceException" error

```
public class Listview_data
{
    public string name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public ImageSource Image
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public string path
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
};


private void ListView_MouseDClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Listview_data lvd = null;
    lvd = DocsListView.SelectedItem as Listview_data;
    MessageBox.Show(lvd.name);
}
```

I have attached screenshot of debugging 
[image]

Comment: Are you sure that your SelecteItem is of Listview_Data type? The debug show the name of a different class `SimpleCube.Documents`, notice also the first letter of the properties in upper case. Please check where you set the DataSource of the DocsListView

Comment: @Steve yes there was a mistake in data source, thank you for suggestions. I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to screenshot `DocsListView.SelectedItem` is of type `SimpleCube.Documents`

so after this line of code `lvd` is null

```
lvd = DocsListView.SelectedItem as Listview_data;
```

And following line of code throws `NullReferenceException` when accessing `lvd.name`

```
MessageBox.Show(lvd.name)
```

So fix your bindings first

Comment: yes I had done mistake in binding, I had put first letter of property in lowercase

Answer (score 1):

According to the debug image posted your code should be

```
private void ListView_MouseDClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    SimpleCube.Documents lvd = null;
    lvd = DocsListView.SelectedItem as SimpleCube.Documents;
    if(lvd != null)
        MessageBox.Show(lvd.Name);
}
```

Or, perhaps, the setting of the Datasource for the ListView should be changed to a Listview_Data list of objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking that the SelectedItem is not null prior to use for example;

```
private void ListView_MouseDClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Listview_data lvd = null;
    lvd = DocsListView.SelectedItem as Listview_data;
    if (lvd == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You should only double click on an item");
        return;
    }

    MessageBox.Show(lvd.name);
}
```

There is the possibility that the SelectedItem property will return null if there is no items selected. Also by casting using 'as' you can also get a null reference exception later on if the object isn't the correct type, although this probably isn't a likely scenario in this case.

John Skeet has written a good article on using 'as' for type casting and checking for null, definitely worth a read ([Casting vs "as" - embracing exceptions](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions.aspx)).